# IDEA+Gradle: exclude sources from tree and compilation?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, exclusionpath

In IDEA 2019 I have created a Gradle project and added the following lines to the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "../src"
            include "com/example/abc/**"
            exclude "com/example/abc/tst/**"
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling the project, the compiler apparently does what I expect: starting from the `../src` folder, it compiles only the `abc` package and subpackages except the `tst` subpackage.

However, in the IDEA sources tree on the left-hand side, the whole content of `src` is displayed. It makes it harder to navigate in the project and to understand what is compiled and what is not.

Obviously, IDEA is parsing the .gradle file because it correctly understands the `..\src` location of my sources. But for some reason it doesn't respect the `include` and `exclude` statements. What should I do to make IDEA display exactly the same content which is being compiled?

I know I can hide a folder using the "Mark directory as excluded" context menu. But this is a bad solution because it forces me to make the same thing twice in different places and discredits the concept of having everything in the .gradle file.

Comment: It does not yet work, please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169124#focus=streamItem-27-2217923.0-0 You could vote for this issue in tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169124

Comment: @Andrey, upvoted that, thanks